# Route::delete in Laravel is not catching Request $request

Tags: php, api, laravel, routes, http-verbs

with this url
http://localhost:8888/api/v1/apartments/delete , I'm trying to delete a determinate apartment without passing the id through the URL. I'm sending data with POSTMAN but I can't catch it with Request or Input classes.

**Routes.php**

```
Route::delete('/api/v1/apartments/delete', 'ApartmentApiController@destroy');
```

**ApartmentApiController**

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
  dd($request->all());
}
```

[image]

In methods like UPDATE Request is working but not here in DELETE. Why is this? I'm a little bit curious and I have not found it.

It's a good practice to delete passing the item id in the URL like this? Should I do like this?
http://localhost:8888/api/v1/apartments/delete/13

Comment: It is best practice not only to have the `id` in the URL when deleting (easier to find what happened from logs when you delete the wrong things) but also to require some kind of confirmation when deleting any database object (it prevents the deletion of items through XSS).

Comment: Just a sidenote, I've had issues with postman and Laravel; Sending data through the actual post route would work, but performing a post request with postman would not. Eventually had to switch to a different REST client; possible you're experiencing this too, but hard to say for sure.

Comment: @grochmal it's all secured with JWT, but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the id in the route:

```
Route::delete('apartments/delete/{id}', 'ApartmentApiController@destroy');
```

You need to inject that in your method along with the `Request` object.

```
public function destroy($id, Request $request)
{
  dd($id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this same problem. I found that I had to change the header from `Accept: application/json` to `content-type: application/json`...